# Change a heading?

Tags: 7, blocks, panels

A panel has an article title that is wrong and I'd like to make it right, but; I can't find where the wrong data is coming from. I'm having a little difficulty identifying the components of Drupal, but; hopefully this question won't be too confusing or improperly described.

On my home page I have a object that has "View, Edit, Panel layout, Panel content" which seems to contain a Welcome Block and Featured Article. The Welcome Block pane-title is something like "Welcome to City Name Library" and I want to change City Name. But, I can't figure out where City Name is coming from.

None of the "View, Edit, Panel layout or Panel content" tabs has that data. Contained within this panel is the Welcome Block which "Configure block" does not show me "City Name" either.

How do I find where "City Name" is located?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What a wretched hassle fixing this with Drupal has been. I resorted to using phpmyadmin to Export the DB, locate the data, edit the panels_pane table pid=3, correct for string length count now everything is hunkydory.